# obtain `src` from captcha image in <img> with puppeteer in headless chrome

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

My end goal is to obtain the base64 text for the captcha image in a page. The code in the page has

```
</div>
<div _ngcontent-qjw-c117 class="mb-16">
<img _ngcontent-qjw-c117 alt="Image verification" width="100" height="50" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...AAEOWcJLXLQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
</div>
```

In Chrome's console, the following works fine:

```js
var yes = document.getElementsByClassName("mb-16")[1].firstElementChild.src;
```

This is great. Now I want to do this with Puppeteer.

In Puppeteer, I have this code:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('theURL');
  const element = await page.$('document.getElementsByClassName("mb-16")[1].firstElementChild.src;');
  console.log(element);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

This fails:

```bash
$ node index.js
file:///Users/.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:225
        throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
              ^

Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'document.getElementsByClassName("mb-16")[1].firstElementChild.src;' is not a valid selector.
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:24
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (file:///Users/.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:225:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ElementHandle.evaluateHandle (file:///Users/...node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/JSHandle.js:94:16)
    at async internalHandler.queryOne (file:///Users.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/QueryHandler.js:25:30)
    at async ElementHandle.$ (file:///.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ElementHandle.js:93:17)
    at async file:///Users/..../index.js:7:19

Node.js v18.12.1
```

How can I obtain that `src` from the `<img` element with Puppeteer? I reviewed other similar questions with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
    
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('theURL', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0', // This will solve your issue
  });

  // ALWAYS USE return INSIDE evaluate BECAUSE IT HAPPENS IN THE DOM AND WE NEED TO RETURN IT TO puppeteer
   const element = await page.evaluate(() => { 
        const element = document.getElementsByClassName("mb-16")[1].firstElementChild.src;
        return element
    });
  console.log(element);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

More info:

[Page.waitForNetworkIdle() method - Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfornetworkidle/)

Comment: do you know how to evaluate further down? That code fails to me like that, I can pass only when declaring `const element = document.getElementsByClassName("mb-16")[1];` if I use the snippet like you mentioned, it fails with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstElementChild')`

Comment: @nahusznaj Try it first using: 
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
So you could observe what happens, maybe the image is not loaded at the moment you execute the script, if you provide an url I could take a look on it.

Comment: https://secure.e-konsulat.gov.pl/placowki/164/sprawy-obywatelskie/wizyty/weryfikacja-obrazkowa this is the page thanks!

Comment: @nahusznaj I edited my previous answer, using waitUntil: 'networkidle0' it will works ok.